# Multiple Instances of Swiper.js on the Same page

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to have Multiple Instances of Swiper on the Same page.

But instead of having to define each instance like this:

```
<div class="swiper-container s1"></div>
<div class="swiper-container s2"></div>
<div class="swiper-container s3"></div>
<script>
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.s1', { /* Options here */ })
var swiper2 = new Swiper('.s2', { /* Options here */ })
var swiper3 = new Swiper('.s3', { /* Options here */ })
</script>
```

I want to be able to pass conf inside `data-swiper` like so:

`<div class="swiper-container" data-swiper="{ direction: 'vertical', loop: true, pagination: { el: '.swiper-pagination' }, navigation: { nextEl: '.swiper-button-next', prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev', }, scrollbar: { el: '.swiper-scrollbar' }">`

My code so far is:

```
function swipr() {
    let swpr = '.swiper-container';

    document.querySelectorAll(swpr).forEach(el => { 
        let conf = el.getAttribute('data-swiper');
        // Initialization
        const swiper = new Swiper(swpr, conf);
        
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { swipr() });
```

but it's not working as expected...

[here's a JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj5tuw0f/1/)

Comment: Are you writing code in script tag or in separate javascript file?

Comment: it's going to be in a separate file

Comment: Do you want to perform some operations on `swiper1`, `swiper2`, `swiper3` ?

Comment: I want every slider to have its own set of rules and I want to define them via `data-swiper`

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem building a plugin and found a method that might work for you. This is compatible with SwiperJS 8.0+

This will allow you to define your parameters in HTML attributes and then have your initialization JS grab those variables and assigned them to each element in a single function.

HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container s1"
        slidesperview="4"
        slidedelay="3000"
>
</div>
<div class="swiper-container s2"
        slidesperview="2"
        slidedelay="6000"
>
</div>
...
```

JS

```
(function($) {

    // Init swipr
    swipr = () => {
        // Check for swiper-container elements in the DOM
        if($('.swiper-container').length) {
            // For each swiper-container define its variables from assigned attributes
            $(".swiper-container").each(function(i) {
                let slides_per_view = $(this).attr('slidesperview');
                let pause_on_hover = $(this).attr('pauseonhover') ? true : false;
                let slide_delay = $(this).attr('slidedelay');
                let swiper = new Swiper($(this)[0], {
                    loop: true,
                    slidesPerView: slides_per_view,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                    autoplay: {
                        delay: slide_delay,
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
     
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { swipr() });
 
})(jQuery);
```